# Cancelling a DispatchWorkItem waiting for execution in DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, swift4

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I am trying to execute two different tasks depending on if the user tapped the screen once or twice in the `touchesBegan` method.

In the process of doing so, I am delaying the execution of the `singleTapTask` by 0.3s to be able to cancel the `DispatchWorkItem` belonging to the `doubleTapTask`.

---

**My approach:**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

        let singleTapTask = DispatchWorkItem {
            // single tap
        }
        let doubleTapTask = DispatchWorkItem {
            // double tap
        }

        if touch.tapCount == 1 {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: singleTapTask)

        } else if touch.tapCount == 2 {
            singleTapTask.cancel()
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: doubleTapTask)

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Issue:**

For some reason the `singleTapTask` is still executed alongside with the `doubleTapTask` even though the `singleTapTask` has been canceled. 
I can not figure out why the `singleTapTask` is executed in the first place and would highly appreciate your help :)

Comment: Why are you not using UIGestureTapRecognizer for this?

Comment: I thought about wanting only a certain part of the screen to be eligible for the single/double touch recognition but I might end up doing so @NikitaGaydukov

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346315/uigesturerecognizer-for-part-of-a-uiview. It will help you restrict the tappable area.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach for this would be to add 2 `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your view (`singleTapGestureRecognizer` and `doubleTapGestureRecognizer`).

The first one configured with `singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1`, the second one with `doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2`.

Now add `singleTapGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: singleTapGestureRecognizer)`

Furthermore, with your approach above you are not targeting sequential single and double taps, but the number of taps at one tap (number of fingers tapping at the same time)